# How to style the entire first row of a table in CSS

Tags: html, css, css-tables

I wanted to know if there's a way to style (background, text, hover effect) the entire first row of a table? I have tried a lot but nothing works. I tried this one too:

```
.category_table td{
background: #000;
color: #fff;
font-weight: bold;}
```

but nothing works. Can somebody please help me out on this?

Comment: You should apply the style to `tr` and not `td` if you want it for an entire row.

Comment: Can you show your HTML?

Comment: `tr:first-child { /*styles here*/ }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll probably have to do this:

HTML:

```
<table><tr class="row1">

<td>Something</td>

<td>Somthing</td>

</tr><tr>

<td>Something</td>

<td>Somthing</td>

</tr></table>
```

CSS:

```
.row { /*Style the  1st row*/

}
.row td { /*style each <td> in the 1st row*/

}
```

Comment: shouldn't the CSS be for `.row1` and `.row1 td`? typo mistake I guess.

Answer (score 0):

You said it yourself, the first ROW, so that is what you need to target.

```
.category_table tbody tr:first-child td { /* styles for first row's cells */ }
```

(I've assumed your table has a `tbody`; if not, remove this part of the selector.)

Answer (score 0):

If you want best browser compatibility add a class to the row. If you only care about newer browsers then you can use the tr:first-child selector

[See this pen for more](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/hjHIJ)

In the above link, you'll notice styles being applied from both in modern browsers. If you view in an old browser (e.g. IE6) then only the colouring styles will take effect the font-size selector wont as its an unsupported selector. If you only want to target new browsers then the first-child doesn't require any changes to your HTML which may or may not be an issue

Comment: It would be better to include the relevant code in the answer than point to a link because the answer will become invalid if the link becomes inactive for any reason. Please dont take this as a negative comment, just a suggestion.

Comment: Fair comment. The benefit of an external resource such as codepen is the result of the CSS applied to the HTML can be easily seen (and played with), whereas inline it cannot. I guess ideally it would contain both...

Answer (score 0):

In the general case, you need to select the first child of the first `thead` or `tbody` child of the table:

```
thead:first-of-type > :first-child,
tbody:first-of-type > :first-child {
  font-weight: bold; /* or whatever you want to set */
}
```

The simpler selector `tr:first-child` works in simple cases where the `table` element contains only one `tbody` element as a child (which is the case when you write just `tr` elements inside it – a single `tbody` is then implied). But in general, a table may contain a `thead` element, a `tfoot` element, and several `tbody` elements.

Note: If there is no `thead` element and there is a `tfoot` element in markup before the `tbody` element(s), it is debatable whether the first `tr` in the `tfoot` element is the first row. In markup it is, but it is rendered last (in default rendering). I have interpreted that `tfoot` elements are to be ignored in this issue.

Support to the CSS selectors used here is good but not universal. For support in all CSS-enabled browsers, add a `class` attribute to the first `tr` element, e.g. `<tr class=first>`, and use a class selector, e.g. `.first`.